# Flex 4 <s:Label Word wrap

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I try to display a text with a Label component.
In some case text is longer than label weight. So I hope to use something like word-wrap option to display text on 2 lines.

```
 <s:BorderContainer height="26" width="100%" borderStyle="inset" id="bcDos">
     <s:Label text="{phpImportant}" 
              textAlign="center"
              fontWeight="bold" 
              color="#FF0730" 
              fontSize="12"
              paddingBottom="1" 
              paddingTop="1"
              width="100%" 
              height="100%" 
              maxDisplayedLines="2"/>
 </s:BorderContainer>
```

With this code, only 1 line is displaying. If there is more text than the label can display, Label truncate the text for me with a truncation indicator such as "...". 
In my dream I'd like to have automatic word-wrap on 2 lines.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've indicated a `height` of `26px` for your `Label`, which for its current font properties (`fontSize`, `fontWeight`, ...) can not show more than one line.

So to show your text on two lines, you've to use an appropriate `height` value or simply keep that property empty so your label will be resized automatically :

```
<s:Label text="{phpImportant}" textAlign="center"
    fontWeight="bold" color="#FF0730" fontSize="12"
    paddingBottom="1" paddingTop="1"
    width="100%" maxDisplayedLines="2"
/>
```

Hope that can help.